# could not match param 'http://my-sub-domain.page.link' with whitelisted URL patterns in this Google project

Tags: regex, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to whitelist [my-sub-domain.page.link/ChangePassword] URL pattern to use this dynamic link to complete Firebase password resetting.  When I try to debug this URL it shows this error:

> The dynamic link has 1 error(s)
>   We could not match param 'http://mydbtesting.page.link' with whitelisted URL patterns in this Google project.

I tried to use the examples that is mentioned in [this link](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429) but the firebase dynamic link couldn't match it.

Can anyone give me a valid regex url pattern that can fix this problem?

Comment: can you share the exact deep link you're trying to whitelist? Or are you trying to whitelist another dynamic link for another dynamic link?

Comment: Plesae provide the original string which contains the sub-string you want to match, as well as the string which you want matched. In this way, we can understand better your need. Also, please show us which regex pattern you used.

Comment: Please can you give me the regex URL of : https://example.android.com/472bc993-cc08-4ed0-8ccd-08429d47c64d/pyagSDh6KLYgsAw9v3uq5xjHyYt2  (i.e : https://example.android.com/UUID/System.currentMillis())